# Nginx refuses to bind to 8080

Tags: nginx, port, varnish

I have setup Varnish to run on port 80 which seems to work fine.

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
varnishd 8005 nobody    7u  IPv4  14055      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
varnishd 8005 nobody    8u  IPv6  14056      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Under available sites in /etc/nginx I have the file default with:

```
server {
  listen 8080;

....
```

nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Why is it still looking for port 80?

Comment: Chances are that one of the referenced files tries to use the default port. At a guess (since it has happened to me all to often), I'd start with `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` (which gets included by default from nginx.conf's `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add

`listen 8080 default;`

And make sure that in other configuration files or virtualhosts there is no other default port 80.

Comment: I noticed I had another config file in the directory that had port 80, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a directive somewhere that is telling nginx to bind to port 80 find it and make the necessary change

```
cd /etc/nginx
grep -rw 80 *
```

Should get you looking in the right place.

Comment: I couldn't find it at first grepping it but when B14D3 send in his anwser it was clear to me where the error was. Sorry but I can only select one good answer.